# Sharepoint 2010: Does free "Foundation" version is enough for document workflow tasks

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, document, sharepoint-workflow

I wonder if Sharepoint-2010 Foundation version meets requirements of a company I work for:

- Free
- Proven extensible document workflow system for Windows
- Able to store gigabytes of document scans inside (Does Sql-Server Express appropriate for that, how does Sharepoint store images?)
- Allows to use electronic signatures
- Notification subsystem, filters (I guess Sharepoint is ok here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SharePoint Foundation itself is free, but **you still need the Windows and SQL Server CALs**.
2. **SharePoint Foundation ships with only one built-in workflow** (the three-state one), so you'll need to develop even the basic ones like approval or collect feedback yourself.
3. SQL Server 2010 Express Edition **limits the database size to 10 GB**. By default, all data (including documents and images) is stored inside the database, but you can use [Remote BLOB Storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748607.aspx) to optimize database storage resources.
4. I guess that **electronic signatures need to be supported rather by client applications** (i.e. Word or Excel), not the SharePoint installation.
5. It depends on your needs, but there are **alerts and views in document libraries**.